# Efficient strategy to do Multiple Webrequests and Response parsing in parralel

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, webrequest

My service has a function which fires a webrequest, parses the responses and doing lot of computes with the response to finally give a collection.

I have to now do multiple invocations to those to get many collections which could be aggregated into one later. I guess I could choose any of this `Parrallel.ForEach and Tasks.StartNew`

Can you advise which could be efficient in handling this scenario having  webrequest processing &  compute.

Comment: If you are *pipelining* data from *IO Bound* sources, it would be better to use *Frameworks* that deal with this sort of situation well, like *TPL DataFlow*, or *RX* with the *async and await pattern*. Using `Parallel.For/Foreach` for *IO bound* work will use up precious thread-pool resources and wont scale well (edited 4 times, omg this is a long day)

Comment: The question is too broad and opinion-based. The efficiency is too vague term without knowledge of specific targets and conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parrallel.ForEach` and `Tasks.StartNew` are for CPU-bound workloads. For I/O-bound workloads you need asynchronity, which is most conveniently provided by `Task.Run(async () => { await ...` Now in your case you have both CPU and I/O bound workloads. The good news is that the async infrastructure handles well CPU-bound workloads too. For example this is perfectly valid:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var webData = await GetWebData(url); // I/O bound
    var parsedList = await Task.Run(() => ParseWebData(webData)); // CPU bound
    await SaveListToDB(parsedList); // I/O bound
}
```

No threads will be blocked during the I/O operations, and a thread-pool thread will do the CPU intensive parsing. From scalability and resources-preservation perspective you can't do much better than that. But if you are willing to tie down all the resources of your machine to get the best performance possible, leaving nothing free for other processes, then your strategy should be to have all your processors/cores busy all the time, while at the same time performing the maximum number of concurrent I/O operations the external world can handle (web servers, filesystems, databases, all have limits at how much work can do at the same time).

A good tool you should look for implementing this strategy is the [TPL Dataflow library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), build-in for .NET Core and available as [a package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) for .NET Framework. If you know nothing about it, it has some learning curve, but not very steep. After 2-3 days of studying you'll feel quite confident that you can write quality and robust production code with it. It has all the tools you need for splitting, joining, transforming, buffering and parallelizing your workload, in a way that makes you feel that you are in control of the process, without micromanaging everything.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Task.WhenAll():

```
    ...
    List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
                var listTaks = list.Select(
                            async e => await DoOne(e)
                        );
                var results = await Task.WhenAll(listTaks);
    ...
```

more at [Task.WhenAll Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8)